# How to access the Cassandra browser terminal running on VirtualBox?

Tags: cassandra, virtualbox

I'm trying to access the Cassandra browser terminal but the reported IP is unreachable.

I'm following the instructions to install Cassandra on VirtualBox [here](http://planetcassandra.org/install-cassandra-ova-on-virtualbox/), and have the following configuration:

[image: DHCP Server Config]

And Cassandra appears to start up appropriately:

[image]

But I'm unable to hit the provided IP (`10.0.0.2`)

[image]

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: And in the video they make it look *so easy!*  Did you change anything on the "Adapter" tab of the "Host only Network Details" box?

Comment: While I initially didn't think so, this ended-up being very similar to an earlier question I answered about VMWare: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555691/connecting-to-cassandra-sandbox-from-windows/27570325#27570325

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I went to [Install Cassandra OVA on VirtualBox](http://planetcassandra.org/install-cassandra-ova-on-virtualbox/) and followed the instructions (like you did). And it didn't work for me, either.

What did work, was messing with the network settings and ultimately switching to a "Bridged" network adapter:

[image]

This put the CassandraVM on my internal network, and I was then able to reach everything from an internal IP (192.168.0.103, in my case).

Also, not sure if it made a difference, but I set Promiscuous Mode to "Allow All."

Comment: Thanks Bryce! After switching the network mode to "Bridged" and Promiscuous Mode to "Allow All" I'm able to hit the terminal via my browser.

Comment: You made my day. It works and it choose my internal ip.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Here's what worked for me (the solution came from [this VirtualBox forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=64856)).

In `Host-only Network Details` select the `Adapter` tab and change the `ipv4` address into something inside the `10.0.0.x` range. I think you should avoid conflicts with settings in the `DHCP Server` tab, thus a suitable choice would be `10.0.0.254`, for example.

[image]

Also, I think you should configure your virtual machine's network settings this way:

- `Attach to`: select `Host-only Adapter`
- `Name`: select `vboxnet0`

[image]

I've also set `Allow All` for `Promiscous Mode`, but I don't know if it's strictly required.

Comment: Nicely done!  It's good to have a few different ways to go about solving problems like this.